# Are there free libraries creating HTML5/Javascript forms for Database Tables?

Tags: javascript, database, html, validation, ddl

My problem is that there are tables defined in back-end which have things like VARCHAR(10), DATE, INT etc? We need to create a HTML5/JS form that can be shown to user so that they can enter a data that is in sync with the database schema definition (which keeps changing)  and then export it to a CSV for further processing. That is if schema definition says 10 char he should be able enter only 10 chars in the field.

Is there some software that can do this dynamically as this should have been solved before?

We are presently thinking of importing the schema using jquery-csv and outputting validate.js rules. Any better suggestions?

Comment: I remember a friend showing me quite a mature and good-looking "backend maker"... sadly I can't recall the name. It was written in PHP.